# CKEditor not displaying with Zurb Foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, zurb-foundation

I'm using CKEditor (gem 'ckeditor') and Foundation in a Rails app and they aren't playing nice together. I've been searching for an answer for a couple days now and have attempted both of these solutions without luck:

[ckeditor wont show up in zurb foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190000/ckeditor-wont-show-up-in-zurb-foundation?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2778

I have isolated that it is an issue with Foundation by creating a completely new test app, adding CKEditor (which worked fine), then adding Foundation (Gemfile + bundle install), and CKEditor then no longer displayed. Here is some sample code from my test app:

```
<style>
  textarea{-moz-box-sizing: content-box;-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;box-sizing: content-box;}
</style>

<%= form_for @thing do |form| -%>
  <div class="field">
  <%= form.cktext_area :name, cols: 50, rows: 20, :class => "someclass", :ckeditor => {:uiColor => "#AADC6E", :toolbar => "mini"} %>
  </div>
<%- end %>
```

I added the styling internally in case the style needed to be added after Foundation styling (I also tried adding it inline on the text area to no avail).

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foundation gem overwrites the application layout file (app/views/layout.html.erb). 
If you use the gem, make sure you still have the link to the application file in assets pipeline ( `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` ). This line should stay in between `<head>` tags. 
Hope this works.

Comment: Thank you! I still had the javascript include tag in my layout file, but it was no longer in the head--that was the key.

Comment: By the way, with this fix there is no need for the additional styling or adding column and row dimensions.